# Dynamically update file

Tags: android, file, search, cloud, store

I have created a file on Android Studio for my app and The users search within the file anytime they click on search button. Is there any way to update the file dynamically? In other words, link it to a cloud database, for example, a public file on google drive, and dynamically change it. So, when the user opens the app, the file gets updated from the file on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using firebase. They offer both database and cloud storage. You can learn more in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: If you give me some more information, I can help you get started.